# how to create a tuple of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

How can I create a tuple of dicts?

**original behaviour:**

```
>>> tuple({'key': 'value'},)
# ('key',)
```

**expected output:**

```
# ({'key': 'value'},)
```

Comment: `({'key': 'value'},)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You passed one argument to the `tuple()` *function*, which converts that argument to a tuple by iteration. Iteration over a dictionary only produces the keys. You'd have similar issues if you tried to put a string or a list object in a tuple like that.

Just put your dictionary in a *tuple literal*:

```
{'key': 'value'},
```

Just a comma is enough. You could put parentheses around that if you wanted to, but in most contexts that's optional:

```
({'key': 'value'},)
```

Or wrap the dictionary in another iterable, like a list, if you must use `tuple()`:

```
tuple([{'key': 'value'}])
```

Comment: looks like the default behaviour is due to dict returning keys as iterable